How to keep a full stop in an `enumitem` item number but remove it from an `\autoref` label
I am using the hyperref package's \autoref command so that I can reference a numbered enumitem's items label number. I am running into an issue where I want the numbers to have a full stop (1.) but not the §1 label as can be seen from the MWE output:

I can remove the full stop for both numbers by removing the full stop before the final brace }
\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.}

however I want the item numbering to have a full stop preferably. I am not sure if this is an enumitem problem or a hyperref one, if it is hyperref then I am not sure I know how to fix it. How could this be achieved please?
I am not committed to \autoref but I just wanted something with the § symbol to be able to link to different items in the lists, I am open to any viable solutions.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\Itemautorefname}{\S\@gobble}
\makeatother

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo \label{intro:one}
\item Bar \label{intro:two}
\item Baz see \autoref{intro:one} or \autoref{intro:two}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


as Ulrike shos this is what the ref option is for,

I don't see a point in autoref here:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*}.,ref=\S\arabic*}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Foo \label{intro:one}
\item Bar \label{intro:two}
\item Baz see \ref{intro:one} or \ref{intro:two}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}


Personally I do find it quite confusing to reference 1. as $1 and I wouldn't do that at all.
